# How to transform the result of a Pandas `GROUPBY` function to the original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a Pandas DataFrame with 6 columns and a custom function that takes counts of the elements in 2 or 3 columns and produces a boolean output. When a `groupby` object is created from the original dataframe and the custom function is applied `df.groupby('col1').apply(myfunc)`, the result is a series whose length is equal to the number of categories of `col1`. How do I expand this output to match the length of the original dataframe? I tried `transform`, but was not able to use the custom function `myfunc` with it.

EDIT:

Here is an example code:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'X':['a','b','c','a','c'], 'Y':['at','bt','ct','at','ct'], 'Z':['q','q','r','r','s']})
print (A)

def myfunc(df):
    return ((df['Z'].nunique()>=2) and (df['Y'].nunique()<2))

A.groupby('X').apply(myfunc)
```

[image: Output]

I would like to expand this output as a new column `Result` such that where there is `a` in column X, the `Result` will be `True`.

Comment: Could you show us some of your code?

Comment: @user7374610, I just added a simple sample code.

Answer (score 1):

You can `map` the groupby back to the original dataframe

```
A['Result'] = A['X'].map(A.groupby('X').apply(myfunc))
```

Result would look like:

```
    X   Y   Z   Result
0   a   at  q   True
1   b   bt  q   False
2   c   ct  r   True
3   a   at  r   True
4   c   ct  s   True
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution may not be the best one, which uses a loop, but it's pretty good I think.

The core idea is you can traverse all the sub-dataframe (`gdf`) by `for i, gdf in gp`. Then add the column `result` (in my example it is `c`) for each sub-dataframe. Finally concat all the sub-dataframe into one.

Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,1,2],'b':['a','b','c','d']})
gp = df.groupby('a')  # group
s = gp.apply(sum)['a'] # apply a func
adf = []

# then create a new dataframe
for i, gdf in gp:
    tdf = gdf.copy()
    tdf.loc[:,'c'] = s.loc[i]
    adf.append(tdf)
pd.concat(adf)
```

from:

```
    a   b
0   1   a
1   2   b
2   1   c
3   2   d
```

to:

```
    a   b   c
0   1   a   2
2   1   c   2
1   2   b   4
3   2   d   4
```